# How to check if the last line in a text box has only one word?

Tags: c#, wpf, string

In the code below, I am assigning a string to text box. The text box text is wrapped, so words will be shifted to the next line if they cannot fit in same line.

**C#:**

```
textbox.Text = "Norma went to bed. It was eleven o'clock. She turned out the light. She lay in bed. It was dark. It was quiet. She couldn't sleep. She closed her eyes.";
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox
    SelectionBrush="#FF54FF50"
    x:Name="textbox" 
    Margin="10,53,0,0" 
    FontSize="24" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Width="341" 
    Height="285" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    TextChanged="Textbox_TextChanged"
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    CaretBrush="Black" 
    BorderBrush="Black" 
    Foreground="Black" 
    FontWeight="Bold" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Padding="0,5,0,0" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Now, with the example above, it may happen that on the last line in the text box the word "Eyes" is the only word due to wrapping. If the last line has only one word, I would like to decrease the font size so that the last line has at least two words.

So, in short, the last line should never have one word only. It may have two or more words.

Example: (Wrong)

```
Norma went to bed. It was
eleven o'clock. She turned 
out the light. She lay in 
bed. It was dark. It was 
quiet. She couldn't 
sleep. She closed her 
eyes.
```

Example: (Right)

```
Norma went to bed. It was
eleven o'clock. She turned 
out the light. She lay in 
bed. It was dark. It was 
quiet. She couldn't 
sleep. She closed her eyes.
```

I am not asking how to increase/decrease the font and on what basis the new font size should be calculated. That is different question that I need to figure out. But first step of my problem is to find out if there is a single word in the last line.

How do I check if the last line in a text box has only one word?

Comment: `Textbox` doesn't expose information on _how_ it's currently displaying text (afaik). You'd probably have to write a custom control for this. Alternatively you could guess and insert newlines in the text itself, instead of trying to change the font size.

Comment: Another question would be how to decide how to change the font - it could be made smaller so "eyes" fits on to the preceding line or larger so that "her" wraps to the next line.

Comment: Is it possible to find out if the word is alone in C #?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Almost anything is possible. This is a little tricky though. The first thought that would come to mind is to place all of the words from the string in an array of strings. Then determine the size of each string (which can be done from the link in my previous comment). If you know the width of the textbox, you can then run a while loop that will check if the last word will fit, if not, then decrease the font and try again.

Comment: Perhaps another alternative is to add a non-breaking space before the last word, ie: `"...She closed her\u00a0eyes."` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis In a quick test for me, that did the trick, nice solution.

Comment: As the question has been closed I cant add an answer but you can get the length of the last line of text in the text box by using the [LineCount property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount(v=vs.110).aspx) & the [GetLineLength method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlinelength(v=vs.110).aspx). You can then extract that length string from the end of the textbox string & check for spaces or other word separators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps a simple solution is to add a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between the last words, ie:

```
"...She closed her\u00a0eyes."
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`LineCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount(v=vs.110).aspx) property and the [`GetLineText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlinetext(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find the last line of text and then check if it contains a space (or any other desired separator) in it.

Comment: Does not work with property `VerticalContentAlignment ="Center"`.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that `GetLineText`, `GetLineLength` and `GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex` return incorrect results when we use `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"`. This looks like a bug to me. You can use the workaround mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5590282/1187211. To set the borders, enclose the `StackPanel` in another `Border` control.

Comment: Another way would be to iterate each character and use the `GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex` function to find the lines, as this function seems not affected by the bug.